# ControlTempate wpf Textbox not showing text and trigger properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am continuing my learning with a small project in *C# WPF*. My current situation is I want to make a border of a `TextBox` change when an error occurs on a user input eg can not parse their input into a decimal number.

After some reading up I have used a control template, the *XAML* is below, but when I run the project the `TextBox` using the control template (*textBox1*) does not show any text and I can not see what I have done wrong. Can any one help please?

Also I am triggering the change with a `IsMouseOver` property just while I learn, but in my project I want to trigger off an error property so in my mind I would need to add to my `TextBox` control a property `IsError` as a bool and behind my code when I test the user input and it fails the Parse I would set the `TextBox` property `IsError` to true and that would trigger the `ControlTemplate` change. However, can this be done or is there a more standed way to do this?
Thanks.

*XAML* of `ControlTemplate`

```
<Window x:Class="TestContentStyle.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="StyleTriggersSample" Height="100" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <!--A ControlTemplate for textbox including error-->
    <ControlTemplate TargetType ="TextBox" x:Key="OnError">
        <TextBox   Name="TextBox"
                    FontSize="28" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    BorderBrush="Silver"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Height="50"
                    Width="120"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                            Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="TextBox"
                            Property="BorderThickness"
                            Value="5" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>



</Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

    <TextBox Text="Tesing1" Margin="146,23,0,0" Name="textBox1" Template="{StaticResource OnError}" />
    <TextBox Text="Testing2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,23,0,0" Name="Test1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: You can accomplish this using built in validation that is shipped with WPF

Comment: The validation methods examples I saw all used viewmodels which are to be frank abit advanced for me

Comment: You're using a `TextBox` inside the `ControlTemplate` of a `TextBox`, and that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, templates define how a control is rendered. They define their whole look.

You're telling the `TextBox` to render itself with another different `TextBox` inside. That means that the `TextBox` you're seeing in your app is not actually the one you've defined inside your `Grid`, with the "Testing1" text, but the one you've defined inside the `ControlTemplate` that has no text set.

But other than that, you don't need a whole new `ControlTemplate` for this. You just need a `Style`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="OnError">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Silver" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="5" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="Tesing1" Margin="146,23,0,0" Name="textBox1" Style="{StaticResource OnError}" />
    <TextBox Text="Testing2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,23,0,0" Name="Test1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
</Grid>
```

Also, in WPF you don't usually use `Margin` to create a layout :P Instead, you should add ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions to your `Grid`, and use the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties on your TextBoxes to specify their location in your view.

Comment: Thanks, funny I started this using a style but thought the ControlTemplate was correct :-( As for the layout, yes I do know the form but this was a temporary project just for testing this out, so I did not bother,  but I will bear it in mind to tidy up before posting. BTW do you know if I can define my own property to the TextBox as I describe for triggering purposes?

Comment: You could extend the `TextBox` class to create your custom textbox, and add your property there. Or you could use attached properties, which are a bit too advanced for your right now, probably.

Comment: Yep the style was good, and thank you for the advice about extending the TextBox class and understanding the limitations us learners have, not all posters get we are learning to walk on this journey and not ready to run with you guys...A new learning project starts extending TextBox class thanks! :-)

Comment: You're welcome! Just a hint, though ;) If you plan on using your new Property in a Trigger, you'll have to make sure it notifies its changes either through the PropertyChanged event (which means your custom TextBox must implement the IPropertyChanged interface)... Or making your property a Dependency Property instead of just a regular one. Dependency Properties are more complex but have a lot of benefits, so it might be worth to check.

Comment: Thanks for the extra advice Going For Dependency Properties might as well stretch myself :-)

Comment: That's the spirit! Once you understand Dependency Properties, Attached Properties become quite straight-forward since they're very similar and based on the same principles.