# Inheritance On default style from Textbox not working and Share Dictionaries

Tags: c#, xaml, dictionary

(For the back story about this question please see [Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503689/controltempate-wpf-textbox-not-showing-text-and-trigger-properties))
To continue learning about WPF I am trying to Extend an TextBox Control and add a Dependency Property which can be used in a Style to put a border around my extended TextBox Control. To help me achieve this I am using this article [basics-of-extending-a-wpf-control](http://putridparrot.com/blog/basics-of-extending-a-wpf-control/).

I have encountered two problems:
1. When I put the style into a Resource Dictionary and try to merge the Resource Dictionary with a file called "generic.xaml" (also tried "Generic.xaml") the style does not take, upon reading this question here [trouble-referencing-a-resource-dictionary-that-contains-a-merged-dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229395/trouble-referencing-a-resource-dictionary-that-contains-a-merged-dictionary) I tried the solution of adding a Style referencing any control but it did not work (all code at the bottom of the question}. Can anyone explain why please?
2. To overcome the problem above I moved my Style into a Window Resource, but I encounted a different problem. I purposely left out the following code from the worked example in my Constructor of my Extended Control

```
static ExTextBox()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExTextBox),
                  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ExTextBox)));
}
```

as I was expecting my control to inherit the default style of the Standard TextBox, which includes the Properties BorderThickness and BorderBrush. However, when I try and Set these Properties with the Setter statement vs2010 says it can not find the Properties. Can someone explain why and if these Properties are not inherited do I have to use a Control Template in my Style to set up a Border around my Control?

My code from problem 1
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Controls.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="StyleTriggersSample" Height="100" Width="300" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Controls">

    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="138*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <my:ExTextBox  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,28,0,0" x:Name="exTextBox1" Text="ExTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,30,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="textBox1" />
    <Button Content="Test" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,0,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
```

My Extended Control

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace Controls
{
public class ExTextBox : TextBlock
{
    public static  DependencyProperty ErrorFlagProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ErrorFlag", typeof(bool),
                   typeof(ExTextBox),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((bool)false) );

    public bool ErrorFlag
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ErrorFlagProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ErrorFlagProperty, value); }
    }

    static ExTextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExTextBox),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ExTextBox)));
     }

   }

 }
```

Controls.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style TargetType="Controls:ExTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Silver" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="5" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/TestContentStyle;component/Controls.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>-->
<!-- Dummy Style, anything you won't use goes -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" />
```

Comment: your control extends TextBlock !! shouldn't it be textbox?

Comment: Also ,where are you merging the generic.xaml to app.xaml?

Comment: @Nikita OMG how silly of me not to spot that text block!  Thank you you are correct.

Comment: @Nikita I understand the merge is automatic for the generic.xaml if it is in a folder called Themes off the project. I have not put the Controls.xaml in the Themes folder as it did not make a difference. The files are set as resources and the build action is copy if newer

Comment: Yes,I agree,its a custom control then.So, any luck after changing textBlock to textBox?

Comment: @Nikita  Will let u know in abit. Just getting kids breakfast and off to school....Rock and roll

Comment: @Nikita The change from TextBlock->TextBox worked - Thanks